# Address of parameters and local variables in function's stack frame

Tags: c, stack

I'm studying c and have encountered this question when i deal with function's stack frame, consider the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void function1(void* a){
   int b = 5;

   printf("para add: %p local add: %p\n", &a, &b);
}

int main(){

    function1(20);
    function1(30);
    function1(40);
    function1(50);
    function1(60);
    function1(70);

    return 0;
}
```

The results are:

```
para add: 0020FF08 local add: 0020FEFC
para add: 0020FF08 local add: 0020FEFC
para add: 0020FF08 local add: 0020FEFC
para add: 0020FF08 local add: 0020FEFC
para add: 0020FF08 local add: 0020FEFC
para add: 0020FF08 local add: 0020FEFC
```

I know that each function will have it's address too, but is the address of each local variable and each parameter in a function always the same?

Comment: `%p` in `printf()` calls for `void*`, not another pointers. Passing data having wrong type to `printf()` invokes *undefined behavior*.

Comment: The C standard does not mandate using a stack or any other memory management technologie. There are well implementations which don't use a stack at all.

Answer (score 1):

No, they are not always the same. It may depend on the stack pointer if stack is used for arguments and local variables in the environment on which the program is ran.

For example, this code got different address in [ideone.com](https://ideone.com/mJiRV1).

```
#include <stdio.h>

void function1(void* a){
   int b = 5;

   printf("para add: %p local add: %p\n", (void*)&a, (void*)&b);
}

void test(void) {
    int testData[100];
    function1(&testData[99]);
}

int main(void){

    function1((void*)20); /* converted in implementation-defined manner */
    test();

    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
para add: 0xbfcce408 local add: 0xbfcce40c
para add: 0xbfcce248 local add: 0xbfcce24c
```

Answer (score 0):

The exact location of parameters and local variable on the stack is **implementation defined**.

That said, generally speaking you'll find local variables closer to the top of the stack than parameters, and on most implementations the stack grows downward.